# Python statsmodels issue with Cython on intel MKL

Tags: python, cython, statsmodels, intel-mkl

I am trying to install statsmodels on Intel MKL 3.6.3 distribution (2018 version 1) on a Windows 7 64bit system.

As dependencies statsmodels' state:

**Dependencies**

statsmodels 0.8 was tested with the following minimal version requirements.

- Python >= 2.6, including Python 3.x
- NumPy >= 1.6
- SciPy >= 0.11
- Pandas >= 0.12
- Patsy >= 0.2.1
- Cython >= 0.24 is required to build
  the code from github but not from a source distribution. Earlier
  versions may work, although you must use Cython >= 0.20.1 if you’re
  on Python 3.4.

When I execute `pip freeze` on Intel Python environment I get:

- Python 3.6.3 MKL
- Numpy 1.13.3
- Scipy 0.19.1
- Pandas 0.20.3
- Patsy 0.4.1
- Cython 0.27.1

The error I get is:

[image]

Comment: Try installing setuptools too. It looks like statsmodels' setup script is doing some hinky stuff to bootstrap setuptools instead of just depending on it.

Comment: I already have it installed. But thanks anyway! This is so weird

Comment: Most likely it has to do with Intel's MKL python version